# Merge two files having the same date

Tags: python, bash

I have two files, `file1` and `file2` which I need to merge as `filex` according to the date. Here is an example:

file1:

```
20150122,735620,iamSelected,CIG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0,iamSelected,GRH,20150122,735620,0.62,-3.0
20150123,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6
20150124,735622,iamSelected,B,20150124,735622,7,-3
20150125,735623,iamSelected,K,20150125,735622,10,6.5
```

file2:

```
20150122,735620,iamSelected,CIGG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0
20150123,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6
20150125,735623,iamSelected,B,20150125,735623,7,-3
20150126,735624,iamSelected,KK,20150126,735624,10,6.5
```

The output `filex` should be as follows:

filex:

```
20150122,735620,iamSelected,CIG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0,iamSelected,GRH,20150122,735620,0.62,-3.0,iamSelected,CIGG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0
20150123,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6
20150124,735622,iamSelected,B,20150124,735622,7,-3
20150125,735623,iamSelected,K,20150125,735622,10,6.5,iamSelected,B,20150125,735623,7,-3
20150126,735624,iamSelected,KK,20150126,735624,10,6.5
```

I have tried:

```
os.system("awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next }{ if($1 in a) $0=$0 OFS a[$1] }1' file1 OFS=',' file2 >output")
```

but it doesn't work!!
Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure why you program in python if your script is in bash

Comment: No i used command line but we can used python program to do it !

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short solution using `join` command:

```
join -j1 -t, -a1 -a2  file1 file2 > filex
```

The `filex` contents:

```
20150122,735620,iamSelected,CIG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0,iamSelected,GRH,20150122,735620,0.62,-3.0,735620,iamSelected,CIGG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0
20150123,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6
20150124,735622,iamSelected,B,20150124,735622,7,-3
20150125,735623,iamSelected,K,20150125,735622,10,6.5,735623,iamSelected,B,20150125,735623,7,-3
20150126,735624,iamSelected,KK,20150126,735624,10,6.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The awk code doesn't work. `a[$1]=$2 FS $3` only stores second and third field of the first file and uses `$1` as the key. Solution below uses compound key `$1 OFS $2`(remove `OFS $2` from the hash references if that's not right), removes them from `$0` and hashes the rest of the string as the data.

Try this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{k=$1 OFS $2;sub(/^([^,]+,){2}/,"");a[k]=$0;next}{print $0 (a[$1 OFS $2]==""?"":OFS) a[$1 OFS $2];delete a[$1 OFS $2]}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file2 file1
20150122,735620,iamSelected,CIG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0,iamSelected,GRH,20150122,735620,0.62,-3.0,iamSelected,CIGG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0
20150123,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6
20150124,735622,iamSelected,B,20150124,735622,7,-3
20150125,735623,iamSelected,K,20150125,735622,10,6.5,iamSelected,B,20150125,735623,7,-3
20150126,735624,iamSelected,KK,20150126,735624,10,6.5
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                                # delimiters
NR==FNR {                                           # file2
    k=$1 OFS $2                                     # construct key for hashing
    sub(/^([^,]+,){2}/,"")                          # remove 2 first fields
    a[k]=$0                                         # hash
    next
}
{                                                   # file1
    print $0 (a[$1 OFS $2]==""?"":OFS) a[$1 OFS $2] # merge and print
    delete a[$1 OFS $2]                             # delete hash entry
}
END {                                               # process non-referred hash entries
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How i can put them in a file ?

Comment: `awk ... file2 file1 > filex` to store the output of the awk to `filex`. Or if you meant the awk code itself, cut and paste what is between `'`s to a file `program.awk` and call it `awk -f program.awk file2 file1 > filex`.

Answer (score 0):

Python code.

```
def file_contents(file_name):
with open(file_name, 'r') as fn:
    return fn.readlines()

f1_cont = sorted(file_contents('file1'))
f2_cont = sorted(file_contents('file2'))

out_put = open('filex', 'w')
for f in f1_cont:
        try:
                for j in xrange(len(f2_cont)):                        if f2_cont[j].startswith(f.split(",")[0]):
                                out_put.write(((f.strip('\n')+','+str(",".join(f2_cont[j].strip('\n').split(",")[2:])))+"\n")  )
                                f2_cont.remove(f2_cont[j])
                                continue
                out_put.write(f+"\n")
        except IndexError:
                pass    
for i in f2_cont:       
        out_put.write(i+"\n")
out_put.close()
```

That produce the out put you wanted [As in you question]

```
20150122,735620,iamSelected,CIG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0,iamSelected,GRH,20150122,735620,0.62,-3.0,iamSelected,CIGG,20150122,735620,4.40902,-0.4255319148934609,-3.0
20150123,735621,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6,iamSelected,A,20150123,735621,5,6,iamSelected,AA,20150123,735621,7,6
20150124,735622,iamSelected,B,20150124,735622,7,-3
20150125,735623,iamSelected,K,20150125,735622,10,6.5,iamSelected,B,20150125,735623,7,-3
20150126,735624,iamSelected,KK,20150126,735624,10,6.5
```